# QlikView's DynamicUpdateCommand() does nothing in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, qlikview

I'm playing with QlikView and was wondering if anyone has any experience with `DynamicUpdateCommand()`?

- I can quite simpy get a .qvw file loaded and to display it on a form.
- I can use `doc.RemoveAllData(true)` to, well, remove all the data.
- I can't get `DynamicUpdateCommand()` to do anything at all...

Literally, `RemoveAllData()` changes what I see (everything vanishes), and `DynamicUpdateCommand()` changes absolutely nothing on the screen at all...

Does anyone know what I should be doing, or am doing wrong?

Sample code outside of my form...

```
QlikView = new Form2();
QlikView.LoadDocument(@"C:\myPath\myDashboard.qvw");
QlikView.Show(this);
QlikView.DoJiggeryPokery(@"INSERT INTO DataRuns (RunID, Value) VALUES (1, 1)");
```

Sample code for my form...

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private QlikView.Doc document; 

    public Form2() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void LoadDocument(string filename) {
        document = axQlikOCX.OpenDocument(filename);
    }

    public void DoJiggeryPokery(string command) {
        //document.RemoveAllData(true);
        document.DynamicUpdateCommand(command);
        //document.Reload(0);
    }
}
```

I'm using the OCX for QlikView 9.0.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been advised by QlikView support that this functionality exists but in unsupported.  As such, we have abandoned this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use QlikView's C# OCX, but in QlikView's "Edit module" (VBScript or JScript) I **activate dynamic update before performing it**:

```
set curDoc = ActiveDocument.GetProperties
curDoc.EnableDynamicDataUpdate = true
ActiveDocument.SetProperties curDoc
set result = ActiveDocument.DynamicUpdateCommand("INSERT INTO DataRuns (RunID, Value) VALUES (1, 1)")
```

Hope you can adapt it for your environment.

Moreover it could be a problem of **license**. In [Release notes for QlikView / QlikView Server 9.00 SR5](http://www.pwc.ch/user_content/editor/files/publ_tls/pwc_qlikview_9.00_sr5.pdf) I read:

> This functionality is freely available in stand-alone QlikView but requires an
>   additional license on QlikView Server.

Or additionally could be a **bug** like this: [DynamicUpdateCommand stops working after QV restart](http://community.qlikview.com/thread/37592).